# Ubuntu does not display after I changed 20-intel.conf file

Tags: recovery-mode

I wanted to change something regarding brightness control.

I changed the `20-intel.conf`. I added a few lines of code to it.

After that Ubuntu is not displaying, it goes blank after boot.

I also tried going into recovery mode with the enable networking option to remove the code from the file.

But I am not able to change the text in the file in the terminal

- as the file is read only
- `chmod` says `operation not permitted`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: and when you let it boot, so by that time it would be on login screen, did you try to go to console? Ctrl + Alt +F2 .... I guess that way you would be able to log in, do the changes (sudo nano) and reboot...I may be wrong, but I would try it.

Answer (score 1):

#### boot into recovery mode

- Switch on your computer.
- Press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the Grub menu.
- Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.
- Select the line ending with `recovery mode`.

#### use a root shell prompt for the edit

Your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

Select the line ending with `Drop to root shell prompt`.

Run the commands

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

---

#### in case `recovery mode` doesn't work

If the file system always stays in read only mode

Try this:

Boot with a live DVD/USB.

Open a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

type

```
$ sudo -i
# fdisk -l
```

Suppose `fdisk` reports  that `/ (root)`, is `/dev/sda1`, continue running:

```
# fsck -y /dev/sda1
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# nano /mnt/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Comment: I ran your above commands. I am using ubuntu 14.04 , so the file system always stays in read only mode. I have to change the file in the dir /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d any other ways ?

Answer (score -1):

finally it worked.

- I started it in recovery mode using the *enable networking* option. it mounted all the file systems.
- I used the commands

  ```
  sudo touch DIRECTORY NAME
  sudo vi FILE NAME
  ```

And then I was able to edit the file and boot normally into graphic version.

And also the brightness control works as well.